# How to use Ngx-Charts customColor function for increasing Opacity of rest of the series and highlighting selected element

Tags: angular, ngx-charts

I am looking to build a stacked vertical bar graph using ngx-charts in which the selected element should be highlighted and rest of the series should be blurred out so as to give an effect of filter. (Sample reference image attached). I tried passing JSON to `activeEntries` property as mentioned in the ngx-charts documentation but it does not work, apparently there are many requests in github on this issue which is yet to be fixed from the ngx team. So as an alternative, I am trying to use `customColors` property which accepts function (excerpt from ngx documentation - custom colors for the chart. Used to override a color for a specific value) , however I am unable to set the opacity of other parts in the series.

[Sample reference image - before selection is done in stacked chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQ5q6.jpg)

[Sample reference image - after selection is done in stacked chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FX93R.jpg)

My code

html

```
 <ngx-charts-bar-vertical-stacked #stackVertical [view]="view" [scheme]="'picnic'" [results]="monthlyRevenueTrendAnalysis" [gradient]="false" [xAxis]="true" [yAxis]="true" [legend]="true" [legendPosition]="'below'" [showXAxisLabel]="false" [showYAxisLabel]="false" [xAxisLabel]="'Month/Year'[yAxisLabel]="'Revenue(in ₹ )'" [animations]="true" [showDataLabel]="true" [barPadding]="8" (select)="onStackSelect($event)" [customColors]="setCustomColors($event)">
```

Component

```
setCustomColors(data) {
const a = data.name;
const b= data.series
let result: any[] = [];
for (let i = 0; i < this.monthlyRevenueTrendAnalysis.length; i++) {
   if (this.monthlyRevenueTrendAnalysis[i].name ! = a) {
      result.push({"name": this.monthlyRevenueTrendAnalysis[i].name,"value": "#ff0000"});  //instead of color how can I increase opacity
   }
   else{
      result.push({"name": this.monthlyRevenueTrendAnalysis[i].name,"value": "#33cc33"});  // instead of color how can I highlight the selected element
   }
}
return result; }
```

EDIT : I have tried applying the same to Pie Chart and it is overriding the default colors on load rather than applying the color on click of a slice in Pie
Please find the stackblitz link for the same

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-291naj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly. It will be helpful if you show you code.

Comment: @isAif : Have updated my question with code and supporting evidences